# Why can I not print an enum's case name in Swift 3?

Tags: swift, charts

I have a enum in Swift 3, I can print its name using following code:

enum definition

```
public enum Foo : Int {
    case F1
}
```

following code will get `F1` in console

```
print(Foo.F1)
```

But when I try to print enums defined in [Charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts)

I can only get `HorizontalAlignment` in console

```
print(Legend.HorizontalAlignment.center)
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the enum is declared as `@objc`.  In [Legend.swift](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/blob/master/Source/Charts/Components/Legend.swift):

```
@objc(ChartLegendHorizontalAlignment)
public enum HorizontalAlignment: Int
{
    case left
    case center
    case right
}
```

Try it yourself, add `@objc` in front of your `Foo` enum and you will see that `Foo` is printed.  While I'm not exactly sure why this happens, it's likely it's due to the way `@objc` changes an enum's debug description, since Objective-C enums are just a series of Integers without any metadata attached.  An `@objc` enum prints its type, while a Swift enum prints its case.

Related discussion: [Why does an @objc enum have a different debug description than a pure Swift enum?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42513337/2415822)

Comment: What should I do if I want to get `center ` in console? I am wrapping Charts with react-native. It has so many enums that I need some factory methods to map js string to enum in swift

Comment: @XuDongWu You don't really have a choice, unless you want to fork the pod and change the class yourself.

Comment: Is there any official doc about  why @objc will lead to this? I am new to swift &oc

Comment: @XuDongWu Not that I know of, I've asked a follow up question here: [Why does an `@objc` enum have a different debug description than a pure Swift enum?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42513337/2415822)